# Postman test is always passing even though it fails

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

While running postman Tests, Test case seems to be always passing
The response body is provided below. I am trying to fetch id when the name is "Erin" and validate that id is 800. Small piece of code that i wrote is below the response body written below.FOr some reason the test always returns true. If for some reason if Erin and 800 are not present still it passes the test.

```
[
 {
  "id":991,
  "name":"Tomy"
 },
 {
  "id":800,
  "name":"Erin"
 }
]
Code:
pm.test("Validate id to be 800", function() {
   var jsonData = pm.response.json();
   for(int i=0; i<responseJson.length;i++){ 
      if(jsonData[i].name=='Erin'){
         pm.expect(jsonData[i].id).to.eql(800);
      }
     }
});
```

Updated the response a bit a below , i wanted my test to fail as "Jack" is 
not found and to pass only if Jack is found

```
pm.test("Validate id to be 800", function () {
  let jsonData = pm.response.json();
  for(i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
     if(jsonData[i].name == 'Jack') {
        pm.expect(jsonData[i].id).to.eql(800);
      }
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That response body doesn't look quite right to me, I would expect to see quotes around the property keys in the objects.

Also, your references were not named correctly and that would pass the test as it wouldn't have caused any reference errors in the scripts.

This should help you out:

```
pm.test("Validate id to be 800", function () {
   let jsonData = pm.response.json();

   for(i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
      if(jsonData[i].name === 'Erin') {
        pm.expect(jsonData[i].id).to.eql(800);
      }
    }
});
```

You could rewrite the test code to something like this:

```
pm.test("Validate id to be 800", () => {
    let jsonData = pm.response.json();

    jsonData.forEach(item => {
        if(item.name === 'Erin') {
            pm.expect(item.id).to.eql(800);
         }
    });
});
```

[image: Postman]

And the Test Results when it fails:

[image]

Comment: Yes true the quotes were missing and i have added them . But the script you gave me, is still having the same issue, it pass even though there  id is not equal to Erin or not equal to 800. Please help me if you can.

Comment: I ran that locally with your example response and even changed the value to force an error in the assertion. There must be something else going on. Did you use my whole script? Can you add an image to the original question so I can see what's actually happening.

Comment: Yes, i tried the same script you have posted. If a tweak a little to as below it still pass where as i wanted it to fail                                                    pm.test("Validate id to be 800", function () {
   let jsonData = pm.response.json();

   for(i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
      if(jsonData[i].name === 'Jack') {
        pm.expect(jsonData[i].id).to.eql(800);
      }
    }
});

Comment: Could you try changing it to `pm.response.json()[0]`?

Comment: Saying it didn't work, doesn't really help. Have you tried console logging the response or even the objects being looped through to see what is getting passed in the if statement. Modify the test to a simple level to see it fail for a different reason. Add an image like I said so more people can visually see what's happening.

Comment: You have a collection runner tag in this post is that what you're using? Do you save the request after making these changes? The runner won't know anything new unless you do that.

Comment: It's going to pass because your expect is dependent on Erin being there, if Erin isn't there it will never do your pm.expect

Comment: You'd need to do something expect Erin to be there, and that Erin's ID is what you want. If Erin is not there it will fail, if Erin is there and ID is wrong it will fail. Only time it Will pass is if Erin is present, and ID is correct